# How to choose between waiting and not waiting in the parent process?

Tags: c, process, fork

Lets say I have two function **x** & **y** and both of these functions are calling another function **z**.

I fork in this function **z**.

What I want to do is the following.

1. If my calling function is **x**. wait for the child to finish in the
   parent process
2. else If the calling function is **y**. do not wait for the child, (as if it
   is running at the same time).

How can I achieve such behavior and if it is even possible ?

or do I have to make two separate functions **z1** & **z2**

where in **z1** i fork and wait and in **z2** I fork and I don't wait.

and I want to do this in c

Comment: What is wrong with passing a 'wait' boolean into z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an argument to `z` indicating whether or not `z` should wait for the child. Alternatively, you could make `z` return the process ID of the child without waiting for it. Then you can manually call `waitpid` in `x` to explicitly wait for the process forked off by `z`:

```
waitpid(z(), NULL, 0);
```

Of course, you need to do error handling as well.

Comment: How would I terminate a program when I am choosing to not waiting. It just freezes at the end. How could I terminate it

Comment: @Pro I need more information to answer this question. Could you post the code that exhibits this problem? It's probably best if you ask a new question for that.

Comment: basically I am doing execvp on a line that contains many commands from a file. And I am trying to run all the commands together. so that the results could be intermixed. Everything works fine, except that when it's done it  doesn't exit the program in the terminal

Comment: @Pro Sorry, no idea. Show me the code (in a separate question) or make a minimal example, then I can help you.